# AVAssetExportSession.exportAsynchronously does not make progress

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avmutablecomposition

Extended AVMutableComposition so that it can be exported.
However, even a 1-second video does not progress at all when export is performed.
I tried to print out the progress, and found that it didn't make any progress at 0.0.

What could be the possible cause?

```
extension AVMutableComposition {

    private struct AssociatedKeys {
        static var initialTransform: CGAffineTransform!
    }

    var initialTransform: CGAffineTransform {
        get {
            objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.initialTransform) as! CGAffineTransform
        }
        set(newValue) {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.initialTransform, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN)
        }
    }

    convenience init(asset: AVAsset) {
        self.init()

        let videoTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).last!
        self.initialTransform = videoTrack.preferredTransform
    
        do {
            try insertTimeRange(CMTimeRange(start: .zero, duration: asset.duration), of: asset, at: .zero)
        }  catch let error {
            debugPrint(error)
        }
    }

    func export() {
        guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: self, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality) else {
            print("Could not create an export session")
        }
            
        let outputURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + "video.mp4")
        exportSession.outputURL = outputURL
        exportSession.outputFileType = .mp4
        exportSession.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
                            
        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
            print(exportSession.progress, exportSession.status.rawValue) // 0.0 1
        }
                        
        exportSession.exportAsynchronously {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you don't retain the `exportSession` (and the `timer`). Both objects are deallocated as soon as you leave the `export()` method. You need to reference them somewhere for as long as the export is running.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted my Mac and iPhone and the problem was solved.